# How can I assign quiz answers a position in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've made a five question quiz with four answers each and want to assign each question/answer its own position in an array. So for example here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SQ.css">
    <script src="SQ.js"></script>
    <title>'Simple Quiz'</title>
</head>
<h3>Let's See What You Know!!</h3>
<body>
<div id="question1" class="div activequestion">
    <p>What is the capital of Washington?</p>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q1" name="Q1">Salem
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q1" name="Q1">Seattle
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q1" name="Q1">Olympia
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q1" name="Q1">Helena

</div>
<div id="question2" class="div">
    <p>How many countries are in Europe?</p>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q2" name="Q2">51
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q2" name="Q2">15
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q2" name="Q2">46
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="q2" name="Q2">27
```

These are the first two questions of my quiz.

I would like to make an array with two sets of data. By that I mean I want question one answer 3 to be [0, 2] and so on. Would this have to be assigned in the Javascript portion of my code or can this be done directly in the html, maybe between the div < >'s for each question/answer?

Additionally how could I check for correct answers at the end of my quiz using this array format? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/ejqb34tt/). All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, **never** assign the same id to multiple elements.

Second, your inputs can be passed on as an array by naming them `name="q1[]"` or `name="questions[q1][]"`

Comment: So something like this?                                                                                 <div id="question1" class="div activequestion" name="Q1[0,0]">
    <p>What is the capital of Washington?</p>
    <input type="radio" class="input" class="q1" name="Q1[0,1]">Salem
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" class="q1" name="Q1[0,2]">Seattle

Comment: Also if that's the case, how do I call on this array later?

Comment: Not [0,2], only one thing per bracket.
It depends on your backend. For example, in php you'd get `$_POST['q1'][0] = "Your first answer"`, a standard array. In NodeJS, it would be JS object `{post_data_container}.q1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the correct answer in the array in Javascript. Or make a hidden element in html to store them. And then according to the question look at the array index and check the answer.

Comment: Ok but how I assign each question/answer it's own spot in an array? Like if I stored the correct answers in an array how would it know what to compare it to if theres not another array with all of the questions and answers?

Comment: its a simple task. Just make an array for answer. And you have given every question an id of q1,q2,. So make a switch case and then look at the selected answer and the value corresponding to the answer array. If it same. Then he has given the correct answer